# Geolocator gps code getting error when select ios project.android it is working

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, gps

Please find the code snippet below that will error in IOS but coming nicly in android device:

```
 aasync  void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
        var position = await 
        locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);

        logi.Text = position.Latitude.ToString();
        lati.Text = position.Longitude.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: i am gating red color on timeoutMilliseconds when i am selecting ios project it is xamarin.form project.

Comment: First of all please put code in "Code block", second of all don't comment with extra information, you should edit the question instead.
Third of all can you show us more code please?

Comment: async  void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
            
            logi.Text = position.Latitude.ToString();
            lati.Text = position.Longitude.ToString();
        }

Comment: Please put the code inside the question not in a comment.

Comment: I don't know if it's the reason but you are missing semicolon one line before.
var position = await.. you have no semicolon after this line.
Can this be the problem?

Comment: var position = await 
                    locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000); complete line it is not semicolon problem and it is working properly in android device only ios having problem .         https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652361/blacky

Comment: I'm not sure how xamarin work about plist and permission on ios, but make sure you asked for location permission from the user and add description to the ios plist.

Comment: and make sure you are using the correct plugin, I looked it up and saw that many people said that the problem is they were using the wrong plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue on iOS but works perfectly on Android.

It turns out the `timeout` parameter you set is too short for the task completion, so it canceled every time.

#### Solution

```
await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Refer to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125984/getpositionasync-works-in-android-but-not-in-ios-11/47153973#47153973)

Comment: Hi,https://stackoverflow.com/users/8187800/cole-xia                                               After that i am gating this error                                                                             Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int' (CS1503) (Clobas.Droid)

Comment: @SurajNathpandey which plugin are you using？

Comment: i am using ->xam.plugin.Geolocator it is xamarin.Forms project

Comment: @SurajNathpandey is it the latest version？